# Delete Duplicates From the Array

Tags: java, arrays

I need some help, guys.
Here is the assignment: Create a program to remove all the duplicates from a random array of integers. For example, if the array has the values 
4, 7, 10, 4, 9, 5, 10, 7, 3, 5
then the array should be changed to
4, 7, 10, 9, 5, 3

The program should consist of two classes DeleteDuplicate and DeleteDuplicateDemo.

The DeleteDuplicate class should do the following
1. Have a method that checks for duplicate values.
2. Keep track of currentsize of array
3. Have a method that Delete duplicates (replace duplicate values with the next value in the array.)

The DeleteDuplicateDemo class should do the following
1. Have your main method.
2. Create a random array with a length of 10 numbers ranging from 1-10.
3. Display original random array.
4. Call(s) to DeleteDuplicate methods to find and remove duplicates.
5. Display new array without duplicates.

Sample Output:
[8, 5, 7, 3, 2, 5, 6, 3, 6, 7]

[8, 5, 7, 3, 2, 6]

Here is the code for DeleteDuplicateDemo:

```
import java.util.*;

public class DeleteDuplicateDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

       Random random = new Random();
        int array[]= new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        {
            array[i] = random.nextInt(10)+ 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        {        
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
   System.out.println();
   DeleteDuplicate class1 = new DeleteDuplicate();
   array = class1.removeDuplicates(array);

 for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        {        
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }

   }
}
```

Here is the code for DeleteDuplicate:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DeleteDuplicate
{
   private static int[] remove(int[] array)
   {
      int current = array[0];
      boolean found = false;

      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
      {
         if (current == array[i] && !found) 
         {
            found = true;
         } 
         else if (current != array[i]) 
         {
           System.out.print(" " + current);
           current = array[i];
           found = false;
         }
    }
       System.out.print(" " + current);
       return array;
   }

    public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] array) {
      // Sorting array to bring duplicates together      
      Arrays.sort(array);

      int[] finalArray = new int[array.length];
      int previous = array[0];
      finalArray[0] = previous;

      for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
         int value = array[i];

         if (previous != value){
            finalArray[i] = value;
         }
         previous = value;
      }
      return finalArray;

      }
}
```

How can I make it work? I only have a problem with calling another class. Thank you!

Comment: `I only have a problem with calling another class.` And what is the problem? The obvious issue I see is that `removeDuplicates` is static, so you don't need an instance of `DeleteDuplicate` to call it. Also, if you find a duplicate `i` is still incremented so you have "holes" in your `finalArray` - was that intended?

Comment: what was remove() supposed to do? I see you use the boolean found to find a duplicate, yet you don't actually use it for anything else outside of the loop..

Comment: remove() is supposed to check for duplicates and keep track of the current size. The problem was that I was not sure how to call a method from another class, DeleteDuplicate. Commentators below helped with that but now the code deletes the smallest value and puts 0's in place of deleted values.

Answer (score 0):

In your `DeleteDuplicateDemo` class, change

```
DeleteDuplicate class1 = new DeleteDuplicate();
array = class1.removeDuplicates(array);
```

to

```
array = DeleteDuplicate.removeDuplicates(array);
```

In your `DeleteDuplicate` class, change

```
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
    int value = array[i];
    if (previous != value){
        finalArray[i] = value;
    }
    previous = value;
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     int value = array[i];
     if (previous != value){
         finalArray[j] = value;
         j++;
     }
     previous = value;
}
```

Then when you are printing out the values of `array` to the console the 2nd time, make sure to do a check for if `array[i] != null` before printing `array[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

The removal code is too complex: rather than making a separate method for removing the item, walk through the array starting at index `1`, and copy from the reading index into the writing index if the data that you write is different from the item at index `i-1`:

```
int rdIndex = 1;
int wrIndex = 1;
while (rdIndex != array.length) {
    if (array[wrIndex-1] != array[rdIndex]) {
        array[wrIndex++] = array[rdIndex];
    }
    rdIndex++;
}
return Arrays.copyOf(array, wrIndex);
```

At the end of the loop `wrIndex` indicates the number of items to be copied into the result array.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/5aCR68)

Comment: Thank you a lot. I wish I could use wrIndex but I need to make it in a complicated way. So the array is printing out, however, it deletes the smallest value of the array and puts 0's in the place of deleted numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] array) {
    return IntStream.of(array).distinct().toArray();
}
```

test:

```
int[] array = {8, 5, 7, 3, 2, 5, 6, 3, 6, 7};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(removeDuplicates(array)));
// -> [8, 5, 7, 3, 2, 6]
```